# How to match optional token in lex

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I have file with strings as below.

```
PORT = en, PIN = P3; 
PORT = dummy[9], PIN = P41;
PORT = dummy[8], PIN = P42;
PORT = dummy[7], PIN = P43;
PORT = dummy[6], PIN = P44;
PORT = dummy[5], PIN = P45;
PORT = dummy[4], PIN = P46;
PORT = dummy[3], PIN = P47;
PORT = dummy[2], PIN = P48;
PORT = dummy[1], PIN = P49;
PORT = dummy[0], PIN = P50;
PORT = out1, PIN = P6;
```

I'm trying to extract `PORT` and `PIN` using `lex` as below.

lex grammer.

```
%%
"="                    { return EQUALS; }
","                    { return COMMA; }
";"                    { return SEMICOLON; }
PORT                   { return PORT; }
PIN                    { return PIN; }
[\[0-9\]]* {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return BUS_PORT;}
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return ALPHANUMERIC;}
"//".* | [\t]          {; }
"/*"[.\n]*"*/"         {; }
\n                     {; }
.                      {; }
%%
```

And respective `yacc` file.

```
%token EQUALS
%token COMMA
%token SEMICOLON
%token PIN
%token PORT
%token <str> ALPHANUMERIC
%token <str> BUS_PORT
%type <str> port_name
%type <str> pin_name

%%

physical_command : sub_command
                 | physical_command sub_command
                 ;
sub_command      : port_command
                 ;

port_command     : PORT EQUALS port_name COMMA PIN EQUALS pin_name SEMICOLON
                 {
                   pm->addPortAndPin(std::string($3),std::string($7));
                 }
                 ;

port_name        : ALPHANUMERIC
                 | ALPHANUMERIC BUS_PORT
                 {
                   $$ = $1;
                 }
                 ;
pin_name         : ALPHANUMERIC
                 {
                   $$ = $1;
                 }
                 ;
%%
```

---

If you see `port` name can be an array type {`dummy[10]`, `dummy[9]`..etc} or normal type.
To parse it I have written rule as below.

```
port_name        : ALPHANUMERIC //for normal type
                 | ALPHANUMERIC BUS_PORT  //for array type
                 {
                   $$ = $1;
                 }
```

And grammar is

```
[\[0-9\]]* {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return BUS_PORT;}
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return ALPHANUMERIC;}
```

**My Question:**

I'm not able to parse array type with the above rules, my output looks like below. Please help me with the rules such that I can parse normal and array type.

```
Port = en       Pin = P3
Port = dummy    Pin = P41 //should have been dummy[9]
Port = dummy    Pin = P42 //should have been dummy[8]
Port = dummy    Pin = P43
Port = dummy    Pin = P44
Port = dummy    Pin = P45
Port = dummy    Pin = P46
Port = dummy    Pin = P47
Port = dummy    Pin = P48
Port = dummy    Pin = P49
Port = dummy    Pin = P50
Port = out1     Pin = P6
```

Comment: You don't. You handle it in the grammar.

Comment: @user207421 can you please shed some light on how to do it.

Comment: Handle `[`, `]`, and the numeric literal inside them as three separate tokens and parse them in the grammar, such that `[0-9]+` returns `NUMERIC` in the lexer, similarly to your rule for ALPHANUMERIC, and in the grammar `BUS_PORT: '[' NUMERIC ']'`.

Comment: @user207421 I was able to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: @user207421 Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array element access operation where every opening '[' should have the corresponding closing ']' is handled at parsing level.

In lex specification,replace

```
[\[0-9\]]* {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return BUS_PORT;}
```

by

```
  [0-9]+   {}
   "["     { return *yytext;} 
   "]"     { return *yytext;}
```

In parser specification, replace

```
  port_name  : ALPHANUMERIC
             | ALPHANUMERIC BUS_PORT { $$ = $1;}
```

by

```
  port_name  : ALPHANUMERIC
             | ALPHANUMERIC '[' BUS_PORT ']' { $$ = $1;}
```

One more solution is, change BUS_PORT token rule to

```
  \[[0-9]+\] {yylval.str =strdup(yytext);return BUS_PORT;}
```

It recognizes [ followed by one or digits followed by ], works only for fixed-number of dimensions